# Elastic Search Stable Version

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic search. We are building a Spring boot application with Elastic search.
Currently, we are bound to use `Spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE.`

*After a lot of R&D, I've finalized to use `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` for integrating my Spring boot application.*

Thinking to setup latest `Elastic search version "7.7.1"`.
**Is it fine to proceed with the latest version or should I go with any previous version of Elastic search for any reason?**

Comment: You have to check release time and new confrontational details regarding elastic-search. If it's compatible or implemented those features then go for it else it becomes useless to adopt latest one instead of going with stable one is batter as per my thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are just starting a new project I would recommend to go for a stable version. So at least you are sure that the problems in your application do not come from the ES.
Later in the development process as you analyse the changelog between releases you can consider if you need the fixes and the new features of the new release, and test that in a new branch.

I guess at the first golive you will end up with a completely different spring release and also a different Elastic stack release if you are doing something substantional.

Comment: Could you please elaborate "which previous version of Elastic search i should use and why not 7.7.1?"

Comment: Major versions of the stack are released quite frequently, with great new features but also breaking changes. It is always wise to read and do research on what these changes mean for your environment before you begin upgrading. Latest is not always the greatest! That can be a reason to choose a major version in favour of a minor version in my perspective.